# How to decide whether a linear subspace over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the cycle space of some graph?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, matroids

**Preliminaries:**

Assume we have a simple graph $G=(V,E)$ (no loops, no multiple edges). If we label the edges with $k=1,\dots,|E|$, its cycle space $C$ can be identified with a linear subspace of $\mathbb{Z}_2^{|E|}$ where $\vec x=(x_1,\dots,x_{|E|})^T\in C$ describes an Eulerian subgraph of $G$ with edges $k$ where $x_k=1$.

Now let $H\leq \mathbb{Z}_2^{L}$ be an *arbitrary* linear subspace given by a basis $B=\{\vec b_1,\dots,\vec b_N\}$ ($N\leq L$) with the only constraint that for all $i=1,\dots,L$ there is at least one element $\vec x\in H$ such that $x_i=1$ (i.e., there are no trivially "unused" components).

Apparently not all such subspaces $H$ can be interpreted as cycle space of some simple graph $G_H$ with $L$ edges. For instance, $H=\operatorname{span}\{\vec x_1,\vec x_2\}$ with $\vec x_1=(1,1,0)^T$ and $\vec x_2=(0,1,1)^T$ cannot occur as cycle space of any simple graph.

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Is there a characteristic property of $B$ (or $H$) to decide whether $H$ is a cycle space of some graph?
> 2. Is there an *efficient* (i.e., polynomial in N and L) algorithm to check this?

My graph theory knowledge is only rudimentary (i.e., self-taught) so that I find it hard to gauge whether this is a trivial textbook question or whether there is more behind it. My literature research did not produce any useful results except for the vague notion that it might be related to *graphic matroids* (for which there is an efficient algorithm by Tutte).

I would be thankful for any hint/explanation/reference that helps in answering the above questions (in particular the second one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matroid theory provides the answers you are looking for.

Given a linear subspace $V$ of an arbitrary vector space let $M$ be any matrix whose kernel is $V$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the [vector matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Matroids_from_linear_algebra) on the columns of $M$. If $V = \mathbb{Z}^n_2$, then $\mathcal{M}$ is called a **binary matroid**. A **graphic matroid** is a binary matroid that does not contain contain the matroids dual to either (1) the graphic matroid of $K_5$ (the complete graph on five vertices) or (2) the graphic matroid of $K_{3,3}$ (the complete bipartite graph). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_matroid#Related_matroids) for more.

The [Macaulay2](https://github.com/Macaulay2/M2) software package [Matroids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04618) is useful for computing with these objects. It allows you to define a matroid from a matrix (or a graph or a hyperplane arrangement, etc) and, using the `hasMinor` method, determine if that matroid has a given matroid as a minor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This confirms my expectations. Regarding your post, I have two questions. What I got is that $V$ is the cycle space of some graph if and only if the binary matroid $\mathcal{M}$ you defined is graphic. Is this correct? And is it possible to check efficiently for the two minors $M(K_5)^*$ and $M(K_{3,3})^*$ for arbitrary binary matroids $\mathcal{M}$? After skimming [this paper](http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_III/contents/ICM_Vol_3_41.pdf), it seems that this is only conjectured (for arbitrary minors, page 830). Is this known for the case of $M(K_5)^*$ and $M(K_{3,3})^*$?

Comment: @NcLang: Yes, $V$ is the binary cycle space of some graph if and only if the matroid of some (equivalently any) matrix representation of $V$ is graphic. As for efficiently checking if a given binary matroid is graphic, I suspect that this is not possible. Of course, checking if two given matroids on the same ground set  are isomorphic is not efficient in general. But both matroid minors we need to detect are completely determined by their Tutte polynomial (see [this paper](https://mat-web.upc.edu/people/anna.de.mier/tesidina4.pdf)), but this may be inefficient to compute as well.

Comment: @NcLang: Also, on SE sites there is no need to write "thank you"s in the comments to people who answer your question. The correct way to thank people for their answer is to upvote the answer using the gray up arrow to the left of the answer. Also, if an answer works for your personally, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: Apparently I am not (yet) allowed to upvote. Regarding efficiency: My literature research produced [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034435) by Tutte. However, I could not immediately extract how the proposed algorithm scales (at least there is no statement about its complexity in the introduction).

Comment: Here is the full paper by Tutte ([link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6bfb/aa277f383e3d73e9344815fb963440f3c1ba.pdf)). The algorithm is in Section 3. [This paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0195669811000242/1-s2.0-S0195669811000242-main.pdf?_tid=ccae0c2b-95c0-4696-a14e-ba41b5a0e06a&acdnat=1539863851_832ff3dbe57215e800c0c43e529408bd) also provides an algorithm that might be of interest.